# why this error? The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2331 in the message file for Application

Tags: perl, cmd

The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2331 in the message file for Application. I tried to rename the file from within a perl program using 'system("ren ref.txt ref1.txt");' while I have closed the file handler for ref.txt earlier

Comment: Context? What were you trying to do when you encountered this error?

Comment: I tried to rename the file from within a perl program using 'system("ren ref.txt ref1.txt");' while I have closed the file handler for ref.txt earlier

Comment: What operating system? the tag `CMD` could imply anything from the beginning of Windows up to Windows8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref: http://www.febooti.com/products/automation-workshop/online-help/events/run-dos-cmd-command/exit-codes/

`0x2331` means `Program is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

`ren` is a command line function, not a stand-alone program. Try

```
system("cmd /k ren ref.txt ref1.txt");
```

instead of

```
system("ren ref.txt ref1.txt");
```